# PHP get keys and values from Nth array in a nested JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, sorting

I'm creating a widget to display the latest share price of a certain company using a JSON list from a free API which updates daily.

I need to identify which key is the most recent and get the closing share price from inside that key.

Here's an example of the JSON generated by the API:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Symbol": "GOOG",
        "2. Last Refreshed": "2019-05-20 11:52:41"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2019-05-20": {
            "1. open": "1144.5000",
            "2. close": "1140.7700"
        },
        "2019-05-17": {
            "1. open": "1168.4700",
            "2. close": "1162.3000"
        },
        "2019-05-16": {
            "1. open": "1164.5100",
            "2. close": "1178.9800"
        }
    }
}
```

To reduce API calls, I save the JSON output from the API to a file on the server and it gets updated once a day.

I can get the value of the closing price with this code:

```
$json = 'jsonfile.json';
$json = json_decode($json, true);
echo $json['Time Series (Daily)']['2019-05-20']['2. close'];
```

But I need the value of the middle key (the date) to be taken from the JSON.

I thought I could do something like this, but I guess the numbers here are treated as strings rather than array positions:

```
echo $json[1][0][1];
```

I can use a loop instead to ignore the key names, get the value of the 3rd key from the top, store it in a variable and use that to echo the closing price:

```
$i = 0;
$dateKey = '';

foreach($json as $row) {
    foreach($row as $key => $val) {
        $i = $i + 1;
        $dateKey = $key;
        if ($i == 3) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

echo $json['Time Series (Daily)'][$dateKey]['2. close'];
```

But this will only work if the newest price is always at the top. I assume it will be... but I don't know enough about JSON to be sure.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can look at [ksort](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_ksort.asp) to sort by date and then pick the first / last one with the help of [array_keys](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_keys.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a value called "last refresh" in Meta Data.
The first ten characters is the date of the last refresh, that is the same as the key of the latest data points in Time series.

So grab the first ten characters and use that to get the latest values.

```
$latest = $arr["Time Series (Daily)"][substr($arr["Meta Data"]["2. Last Refreshed"],0,10)];

var_dump($latest);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["1. open"]=>
  string(9) "1144.5000"
  ["2. close"]=>
  string(9) "1140.7700"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/6AIOf

This means there is no need to loop or sort the data in the array/json.

To only get the close value use:

```
$latestClose = $arr["Time Series (Daily)"][substr($arr["Meta Data"]["2. Last Refreshed"],0,10)]["2. close"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Reverse sort on the keys (dates) and then pick the fist element with `reset`:

```
krsort($array['Time Series (Daily)']);
echo reset($array['Time Series (Daily)'])['2. close'];
```

You can get the key (date) as well using `key`:

```
echo key($array['Time Series (Daily)']);
```

So if you need both, just get the key first:

```
$date = key($array['Time Series (Daily)']);
echo $array['Time Series (Daily)'][$date]['2. close'];
```

Conversely you can sort and pick the last with `end`:

```
ksort($array['Time Series (Daily)']);
echo end($array['Time Series (Daily)'])['2. close'];
```